# Manually set time on timer built with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I have a timer I am using for time tracking.  The timer works great when I click Start or Stop.  Now I am trying to allow for the user to click on the `#time` tag to manually edit the time.  Once they edit the time manually by clicking on the timer and click start it should start from that "time" and when they click stop it should update the hidden `input#counter` tag to convert that into milliseconds.

*My Question is how do I allow the user to edit the time manually so when they click start/stop the timer works as expected based on the new time? For example, if I double click on the time and make it 10:00:00 and press start it should start from 10:00:00, otherwise it is updating the hidden input so when I click submit it saves the updated time*

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4pu3x62g/

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group timer">
    <span id="time"></span>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <input class="btn btn-success col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" type="button" value="start" onclick="start();">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
        <input class="btn btn-danger col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" type="button" value="stop" onclick="stop();">
    </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" value="" id="counter" name="counter" />
```

**Here is the Timer JS**

```
var clsStopwatch = function () {

  var startAt = 0;
  var lapTime = 0;

  var now = function () {
      return (new Date()).getTime();
  };

  this.start = function () {
      startAt = startAt ? startAt : now();
  };

  this.stop = function () {
      lapTime = startAt ? lapTime + now() - startAt : lapTime;
      startAt = 0;
  };

  this.time = function () {
      return lapTime + (startAt ? now() - startAt : 0);
  };
};

var x = new clsStopwatch();
var $time;
var clocktimer;

function pad(num, size) {
  var s = "0000" + num;
  return s.substr(s.length - size);
}

function formatTime(time) {
  var h = m = s = ms = 0;
  var newTime = '';

  h = Math.floor(time / (3600 * 1000));
  time = time % (3600 * 1000);
  m = Math.floor(time / (60 * 1000));
  time = time % (60 * 1000);
  s = Math.floor(time / 1000);
  ms = time % 1000;

  newTime = pad(h, 2) + ':' + pad(m, 2) + ':' + pad(s, 2);
  //newTime = pad(h, 2) + ':' + pad(m, 2) + ':' + pad(s, 2) + ':' + pad(ms, 2);
  return newTime;
}

function show() {
    $time = document.getElementById('time');
    update();
}

function update() {
    $time.innerHTML = formatTime(x.time());
}

function start() {
  clocktimer = setInterval("update()", 1);
  x.start();
}

function millisecondsToHours(amountMS) {
  return amountMS / 3600000;
}

function stop() {
  x.stop();
  document.getElementById('counter').value = millisecondsToHours(x.time());
  clearInterval(clocktimer);
}
```

**Here is the plugin to make the span#time editable:**

```
//plugin to make any element text editable
$.fn.extend({
    editable: function () {
        $(this).each(function () {
            var $el = $(this),
            $edittextbox = $('<input type="text"></input>').css('min-width', $el.width()),
            submitChanges = function () {
                if ($edittextbox.val() !== '') {
                    $el.html($edittextbox.val());
                    $el.show();
                    $el.trigger('editsubmit', [$el.html()]);
                    $(document).unbind('click', submitChanges);
                    $edittextbox.detach();
                }
            },
            tempVal;
            $edittextbox.click(function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            });

            $el.dblclick(function (e) {
                tempVal = $el.html();
                $edittextbox.val(tempVal).insertBefore(this)
                .bind('keypress', function (e) {
                    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                    if (code == 13) {
                        submitChanges();
                    }
                }).select();
                $el.hide();
                $(document).click(submitChanges);
            });
        });
        return this;
    }
});
```

**Here is where the event fires:**

```
//implement editable plugin
$('span#time').editable().on('editsubmit', function (event, val) {
    //Need to trigger the timer with the new val from here

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Run this snippet, its self explanatory.

```js
$(function() {

  // Some global variables
  var startTime = 0,
      elapsed   = 0,
      timerId   = 0,
      $timer    = $("h1 span");
  
  function formatTime(time) {
    var hrs = Math.floor(time / 60 / 60 / 1000),
        min = Math.floor((time - hrs*60*60*1000) / 60 / 1000),
        sec = Math.floor((time - hrs*60*60*1000 - min*60*1000) / 1000);
    
    hrs = hrs < 10 ? "0" + hrs : hrs;
    min = min < 10 ? "0" + min : min;
    sec = sec < 10 ? "0" + sec : sec;
    
    return hrs + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
  }
  
  function elapsedTimeFrom(time) {
    return formatTime(time - startTime + elapsed);
  }
  
  function showElapsed() {
    $timer.text(elapsedTimeFrom(Date.now()));
  }
  
  function startTimer() {
    // React only if timer is stopped
    startTime = startTime || Date.now();
    timerId = timerId || setInterval(showElapsed, 1000);
  }
  
  function pauseTimer() {
    // React only if timer is running
    if (timerId) {
      clearInterval(timerId);
      elapsed += Date.now() - startTime;
      startTime = 0;
      timerId = 0;
    }
  }
  
  function resetTimer() {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    $timer.text("00:00:00");
    startTime = 0;
    elapsed = 0;
    timerId = 0;
  }

  function editTimer() {
    pauseTimer();
    $timer.prop("contenteditable", true);
    $timer.css("border", "1px solid red");
  }

  function setElapsed() {
    var time = $timer.text(),
        arr  = time.split(":");
    $timer.prop("contenteditable", false);
    $timer.css("border", "1px solid black");
    elapsed = parseInt(arr[0]*60*60, 10);
    elapsed += parseInt(arr[1]*60, 10);
    elapsed += parseInt(arr[2], 10);
    elapsed *= 1000;
  }
  
  function sendTime() {
    pauseTimer();
    // Set hidden input value before send
    $("[name='time']").val(formatTime(elapsed));
  }

  $("[name='start']").click(startTimer);
  $("[name='stop']").click(pauseTimer); 
  $("[name='reset']").click(resetTimer);
  $timer.dblclick(editTimer);
  $timer.blur(setElapsed);
  $("form").submit(sendTime);
  
});
```

```css
h1, h3, form { 
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h1 span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Double click on timer to edit time</h3>
<h1><span>00:00:00</span></h1>

<form action="#" method="post">
  <input type="button" name="start" value="Start">
  <input type="button" name="stop" value="Stop">
  <input type="button" name="reset" value="Reset">
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="Submit">
  <input type="hidden" name="time" value="00:00:00">
</form>

<h3>Multiple clicks on buttons is properly handled also</h3>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is great but it is missing the #counter hidden input tag.  When submit was pressed the value of #counter is what was sent to the database.  It was  a conversion of the time to hourly.  For example 01:00:00 would give the #counter value 1.0 - this is used to invoice for time to give some perspective to it.  Any chance on adding that back in?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your example on how to tie in my hidden #counter input tag?  When stop is pressed it calculates what is in the time field 00:00:00 to an hourly decimal like 0.0000 for billing the tracked time.

Comment: Are you able to help me have your solution convert the hidden input value to decimal (like a billable invoice item and my questions example) so I can accept your answer?